# JavaScript error with connecting words

Tags: javascript, words

I have syntax error like this:

```
...href="http://www.dmoz.org/search?q='+do-crafts.ru+'" rel="nofollow" target="_bla...
```

It happens only for this query. Problem only in "do-crafts.ru". For "docrafts.ru" - normally and for other domain its OK. How can I decide it?

Comment: What is `do-crafts.ru`? Is it supposed to be a JavaScript object, whose value you wish to substitute? `-`'s are not permitted in variable names. Furthermore, this seems to be entirely JavaScript, with no jQuery in sight. If you're in the middle of a longer string, you need to escape the `'` using ``\\'``.

Answer (score 0):

the single quotes around the q parameter are invalid

```
href="http://www.dmoz.org/search?q=do-crafts.ru"
```

Comment: Sorry. It is in js code: .html('<a href="http://www.dmoz.org/search?q='+<?php echo $url; ?>+'" rel="nofollow" target="_blank"><b>Да</b></a>'); How it would be?